# SQL Query order by difference in multiple fields

Tags: sql

I have a table  `clientInfo` that I need to sort based on a calculated value based on 4 different fields.

Each row has the fields `Datestart`,`TimeStart`,`DateEnd` and `TimeEnd`.

I need to sort the resultset by the difference between Date/Time started and Date/Time ended so that the longest duration between the 2 is on top and the shortest is on bottom.

Can this kind of complex calculation sorting be done in SQL?

Basically I need

```
Select * 
From [ClientInfo] 
Order By <duration> DESC
```

Comment: Of course. What platform are you using? Microsoft, MySQL? What data type are those field? Because if they were `datetime`, you could have date and time in the same field. You only need to do something like `ORDER BY DateTimeEnd - DateTimeStart`. Given your columns, you first need to create a valid `datetime` from a date+time column pair.

Comment: I am using ASP to display this data in a web portal for the end user. The datatypes for the fields are `[DateStart]` and `[DateEnd]` are simply the `date` datatype while `[TimeStart]`, and `[TimeEnd]` are `time(0)` datatype. I didn't build the table originally and there is far too much data to restructure it now.  I have been just creating a `dateTime` object in ASP and displaying the difference in the times, but now the users want it sorted by this difference. This help?

Comment: @Dead_Jester, you probably can order results in your application, not DB, right?

Comment: @Andrew Looking again at what you wrote, can I do something like `([DateEnd] - [DateStart]) + ([TimeEnd] - [TimeStart])`?

Comment: @ZuoLi Not sure I am following you. I am trying to do the sorting on the application end (.ASP) and then display the results in a table that is properly sorted.

Comment: @Dead_Jester, what structure are you using in your application to work with data from DB?

Comment: @Dead_Jester, basically yes, but a bit different. Try `ORDER BY ([DateEnd] + [TimeEnd]) - ([DateStart] + [TimeStart])`. If it tells you it can't add the values, add this cast in the dates: `CAST([DateStart] AS DATETIME)` (no need to cast the times).

Comment: @ZuoLi I am using .ASP and passing a string variable containing my query to a ADODB.Connection to generate a recordset. I am then simply moving through that recordset and displaying the data in a table for the user to view.

Comment: @Dead_Jester, you still haven't said what SQL platform you are using, only the web platform, which doesn't matter right now. :)

Comment: @Andrew You sir are a life saver! I got it working, it did require the cast statement then it worked like a dream! Please post this as an answer so that I can give you credit.

Comment: @Dead_Jester I'm glad it worked. :) I had already dared to post the answer right after my comment, heh. Thanks for the compliment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments, I think this should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM [ClientInfo]
ORDER BY (CAST([DateEnd] AS DATETIME) + [TimeEnd]) - (CAST([DateStart] AS DATETIME) + [TimeStart]) DESC
```